# How do I set up an SSH SOCKS proxy with Gnome SSH Tunnel Manager?

Tags: ssh, tunnel, port-forwarding, aws

Generally I use this command to create a local Socks proxy via SSH Tunneling

```
ssh -ND 7777 -i google.pem ubuntu@107.20.x.x
```

Then i configure my applications to use Socks proxy on localhost (i.e. 127.0.0.1 )

And it works as expected.

I recently came across a Gnome Application, [Gnome SSH Tunnel Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gstm/), also available in the repositories as `gstm`. GSTM has more features which I need, like Auto Restart and Auto connect on Start up

I am unable to use it as per my requirement.

Here's my GSTM setup:

[image]

And the ports on the server I'm trying to connect to:

[image]

Comment: Ehmm where is the question? Could you provide more info?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting up the redirection incorrectly. To get the SOCKS proxy you need to set up a dynamic redirect -- just one different click (see screenshot). You just need to set the port you want to use on localhost (here, 8888), and leave the remaining as is (n/a).

[image]

Comment: I was just going to do it, system pulled me back. I has some time limit.

Comment: No, ath9k is still pending. I managed to change reg domain.But it reads it from EPPROM and therefore i can't override it. I need to patch drivers to override that.

Comment: Thanks. Re ath9k I think you need to rebuild the crda package after modifying the source. I will try to answer that soon.

Comment: Do you also own same card? I tried to do CRDA, but it is also not working for me or may be i just did it wrong.

Comment: I came across this patch http://patches.aircrack-ng.org/ath9k_regdomain_override.patch . But it is bit outdated and not working anymore.

Comment: No, but I do have an OpenWRT router using ath9k :)

Comment: This patch is already included in ath9k drivers for OpenWRT?